# How to generate 1 to 1 Source Map?

Tags: source-maps

How to generate Source Map if the Source and Target are exactly the same?
One possible way is to write mapping for every single character in the file, like

```
x in source == x in target
```

It works, but the resulting Source Map size is huge. Is there any better way to do it?

P.S.

Why do I need such a strange thing? Because I need to join multiple source maps (batch).

```
a.js -- (possible) transformations --> |
...                                    | -- join --> batch.js.map
x.js -- (possible) transformations --> |
```

In development we don't use minifications (so there's no initial source map for JS file), but still use batches, and I need source map (1to1 would be fine) to produce source map for the batch (I post-process source maps with special processor that sets correct offsets for batch source map, etc., but it needs a source map to start with).

Comment: What are you using to produce source maps? Have you tried this: https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/ ? I would hope it is smarter than to generate a huge source map i this case.

Comment: I solved it by generating 1to1 for each line, not for each symbol.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to create an identity source map:

1. You could use the [generate-source-map package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-source-map). It works only for javascript files; it parses them and generates one mapping for each javascript token (operators, identifiers etc). Best quality maps but at the cost of generation time and map size.

   ```
   var generate = require('generate-source-map');
   var fs = require('fs');

   var file = 'test.js';

   var map = generate({
     source: fs.readFileSync(file),
     sourceFile: file
   });

   fs.writeFileSync(file + '.map', map.toString());
   ```
2. Then there's the more generic [source-list-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-list-map). It works for any text file and generates 1-to-1 line mappings. Less detailed, probably faster and smaller maps.

   ```
   var SourceListMap = require('source-list-map').SourceListMap;
   var fs = require('fs');

   var file = 'test.js';

   var sourceListMap = new SourceListMap();
   var fileContents = fs.readFileSync(file).toString();
   sourceListMap.add(fileContents, file, fileContents);
   var map = sourceListMap.toStringWithSourceMap({ file: file });

   fs.writeFileSync(file + '.map', JSON.stringify(map));
   ```
3. For ultimate flexibility you could use the [source-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map) package and do the splitting yourself:

   ```
   var sourceMap = require('source-map');
   var sourceMapResolve = require('source-map-resolve');
   var fs = require('fs');

   var file = 'test.js';

   var fileContents = fs.readFileSync(file).toString();
   var chunks = [];
   var line = 1;
   fileContents.match(/^[^\r\n]*(?:\r\n?|\n?)/mg).forEach(function(token) {
     if (!/^\s*$/.test(token)) {
       chunks.push(new sourceMap.SourceNode(line, 0, file,         token));
     }
     ++line;
   });
   var node = new sourceMap.SourceNode(null, null, null, chunks);
   node.setSourceContent(file, fileContents);
   var result = node.toStringWithSourceMap({file: file});

   fs.writeFileSync(file + '.map', result.map);
   ```

The two last ones also provide additional functionality e.g. for merging multiple files together.